# Improving performance of a query update that uses md5

Tags: postgresql, performance, update, query-performance

I need to optimize this query, or change some configuration, because execution takes too much time.

#### Query

```
with rows as (
update hotmail.clean_us_usdataclean_1 set offers_excluded=case 
when  
offers_excluded!='' and  
offers_excluded is not null and 
offers_excluded not like '%,80' and
offers_excluded not like '80,%' and
offers_excluded!='80'  then offers_excluded || ',' || '80' else '80'  END
where md5(email::text) in (select email from supp.xxc4u0p5ce74l8co5)
RETURNING 1
)
SELECT count(*) FROM rows;
```

I have a php script that runs through all the tables in the schema, and does the same thing. When dealing with 2m-8m it takes around 30 min to complete, but when I try it with 59m it is so slow, and seems to get stuck on some tables.

#### Query Plan

```
Aggregate  (cost=1151032.31..1151032.32 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=143740.697..143740.698 rows=1 loops=1)
  CTE rows
    ->  Update on clean_us_usdataclean_1  (cost=1124740.33..1145407.31 rows=250000 width=507) (actual time=140845.110..143656.250 rows=51095 loops=1)
          ->  Hash Join  (cost=1124740.33..1145407.31 rows=250000 width=507) (actual time=140844.921..143462.910 rows=51095 loops=1)
                Hash Cond: (md5(clean_us_usdataclean_1.email) = (xxqzu5mbuoz3kypgtrono4n1l.email)::text)
                ->  Seq Scan on clean_us_usdataclean_1  (cost=0.00..9416.99 rows=499999 width=472) (actual time=0.021..361.794 rows=499999 loops=1)
                ->  Hash  (cost=1124368.51..1124368.51 rows=29746 width=22) (actual time=140843.991..140843.991 rows=21646140 loops=1)
                      Buckets: 8388608 (originally 32768)  Batches: 2 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 815899kB
                      ->  HashAggregate  (cost=1124071.05..1124368.51 rows=29746 width=22) (actual time=101204.068..124867.571 rows=21646140 loops=1)
                            Group Key: (xxqzu5mbuoz3kypgtrono4n1l.email)::text
                            ->  Seq Scan on xxqzu5mbuoz3kypgtrono4n1l  (cost=0.00..975465.04 rows=59442404 width=22) (actual time=0.157..33816.356 rows=59442522 loops=1)
  ->  CTE Scan on rows  (cost=0.00..5000.00 rows=250000 width=0) (actual time=140845.117..143716.370 rows=51095 loops=1)
Planning time: 1.111 ms
Execution time: 143847.156 ms
```

Comment: I'm unclear on what exactly is getting too slow - the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output you've posted seems to include the table with 59mil rows (`xxqzu5mbuoz3kypgtrono4n1l` has 59,442,522 rows) but only took 143847 milliseconds - 143 seconds, or 2m23s - to execute, a lot less than 30 minutes. Am I correct in understanding that the PHP bit swaps out table names, and this is the `ANALYZE` output for one of the queries that completed?

Comment: adamkg yes the php script loop through all database tables the odd thing is smaller table with like 30 record take more time than that 5 min to 10 min

Comment: also when the update is running i see postmaster using 100% of CPU is that normal

Answer (score 0):

An index on md5(email) can probably help:

```
CREATE INDEX "clean_us_usdataclean_1_md5_email" 
  ON  hotmail.clean_us_usdataclean_1 (md5(email::text));
```

but will probably take a long time to build.

It won't work if the cast to text is not immutable (eg if email was a timestamptz)